# What to use instead of sendkey in selenium when inputting a double value

Tags: selenium, sendkeys

I am trying to do a calculation and then input the result in to a field using Selenium Web Driver. But am getting the error "The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the 
 arguments (double)"

Below is my code:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ProjectOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.techno-geek.co.uk/SeleniumPractice/webform1.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='continue']")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='COB']")).sendKeys("Toronto");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DOB']")).sendKeys("19th January 1986");  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='color']")).sendKeys("Cream");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='food']")).sendKeys("Pizza");


        double a = 14.867;
        double b = 67.902;
        double c = 22567.325;
        double d = 76.908;
        double r1 = a * b;
        double r2 = c/d;


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("multiply")).sendKeys(r1);//1009.49903


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("divide")).sendKeys(r2);//293.432738


    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use sendKeys(String.valueOf(doublevalue) instead of sendKeys(value). The below code worked for me

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("multiply")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(r1));//1009.49903


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("divide")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(r2));//293.432738
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert into String format using `String.valueOf(doublevalue)` that works me